# How to have integration test visit path+parameters: e.g.: url.com/users?parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, wice-grid

I'm using the [wice_grid gem](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#basics) for tables/grids. This gem offers sorting capability. If I for example sort on username by clicking that column's header, this converts in the browser to: `www.url.com/users?grid[order]=username&grid[order_direction]=asc` and it sorts the column on username in ascending order.

Now, I would like to test for sorting in an integration test. **But how can I initiate a sorting in an integration test (as if the column's header is clicked)?**

I have tried:

- `get users_path?grid[order]=fullname&grid[order_direction]=asc`
- `get users_path(grid[order]=fullname,grid[order_direction]=asc)`

But these don't seem to be the correct ways and generate errors.

A grid/column may for example look as follows in a view page:

```
<%= grid(@users_grid, show_filters: :when_filtered, html: {class: 'my-grid'}) do |g|
  g.column name: 'Username', attribute: 'username', auto_reload: true
end %>
```

Comment: if it's an integration test can you click on the sortable field and test like so?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The column header is indeed clickable but this is something managed/organized by the gem. So there not a special sorting route or something like that I can use.

Comment: but rather than check the route, why not check the contents of the page.  ie `click sortable_column` then `expect(page.table.rows.first).to include "Some first item"`

Comment: Okay, that's something I'm not familiar with. What would be the code for `click sortable_column`? (I assume that's not the literal code?) I'll add an example of a column to the OP.

Comment: Are you looking for a RSpec or test-unit answer?

Comment: Assuming I understand these terms correctly (RSpec is when you first write tests and then develop, while a test-unit answer would be when you first program it and then developed tests), it is a test-unit answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Nick: no, you misunderstood. Rspec and test-unit are the two widely used testing frameworks with different approaches to code (rspec favors DSL and "human readable" language, testunit favors simplicity and low overhead). The question was: which one of these frameworks you use?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'm using the same setup as [railstutorial.org](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-advanced_testing_setup). A piece of test code might for example be `get user_path(@user1)` `assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_path(@user1), count: 1`. But I'm not sure then that I use any of the two testing frameworks...